# How to extract some content with PHP DOM OBJECT?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, object

I have a problem with a php DOM Object
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Is it possible only to show content from the third  tag and the second  tag in that table?

```
/*** a new dom object ***/ 
$dom = new domDocument; 

/*** load the html into the object ***/ 
@$dom->loadHTML($html); 

/*** discard white space ***/ 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

/*** the table by its tag name ***/ 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 

/*** get all rows from the table ***/ 
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 

/*** loop over the table rows ***/ 
foreach ($rows as $row) 
{ 
    /*** get each column by tag name ***/ 
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

    /*** echo the values ***/ 
    echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
    echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
    echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
    echo $cols->item(3)->nodeValue.'<br />';
    echo $cols->item(4)->nodeValue.'<br />';
    echo $cols->item(5)->nodeValue.'<br />';
    echo '<hr />'; 
}
```

EDIT:

I get this error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in

```
<?php

/*** a new dom object ***/ 
$dom = new domDocument; 

/*** load the html into the object ***/ 
@$dom->loadHTML('content.html'); 

/*** discard white space ***/ 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$selected = $xpath->query('//table/tr/td[first()+1]');
echo $selected[0]->nodeValue;
?>
```

Edit2:

```
<?php

$output = file_get_contents('test.php');

/*** a new dom object ***/ 
$dom = new domDocument; 

/*** load the html into the object ***/ 
@$dom->loadHTML($output); 

/*** discard white space ***/ 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

/*** the table by its tag name ***/ 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');//get all the tables

if($tables->length > 2) { //check there are more than 2

    $thirdTable = $tables->item(2);

    $cols = $thirdTable->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

    /*** echo the values ***/ 
    echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
    echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
    echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
    echo $cols->item(3)->nodeValue.'<br />';
    echo $cols->item(4)->nodeValue.'<br />';
    echo $cols->item(5)->nodeValue.'<br />';
    echo '<hr />'; 
}

?>
```

EDIT3 - This code only shows content from the third table tag. But it also need only to show content from the second tr tag in the third table.

```
$html = file_get_contents('content.html');

/*** a new dom object ***/ 
$dom = new domDocument; 

/*** load the html into the object ***/ 
@$dom->loadHTML($html); 

/*** discard white space ***/ 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

/*** the table by its tag name ***/ 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 

/*** get all rows from the table ***/ 
$rows = $tables->item(2)->getElementsByTagName('tr')->item(1); 

/*** loop over the table rows ***/ 
foreach ($rows as $row) 
{ 
    /*** get each column by tag name ***/ 
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

    /*** echo the values ***/ 
    echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
    echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
    echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
    echo $cols->item(3)->nodeValue.'<br />';
    echo $cols->item(4)->nodeValue.'<br />';
    echo $cols->item(5)->nodeValue.'<br />';
    echo '<hr />'; 
}
```

Comment: I have HTMl content in the $html variable.

Comment: for the first syntax error, it is because of the [], use ->item(0) instead of bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your problem. With `$cols->item(2)` you got the second DOMElement you need.

If you just want the first (or the second...) you can use XPath

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$selected = $xpath->query('//table/tr/td[first()+1] | //table/tr/td[first()+2]');
echo $selected[0]->nodeValue;
```

If you do not want to use DOMXPath, you can stay with your getElementsByTagName
First you get all the tables
then you check there are more than 2 
then you take the third
then you take the tr element
you keep in an array the second and the third

```
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');//get all the tables
if($tables->length > 2){//check there are more than 2
    $thirdTable = $tables->item(2);
    //get the tr then td
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use DOMXpath with foreach?
I need it to foreach every <tr> in the table.

Comment: the query I gave you returns every second and third TD of each tr of each table. The return value is traversable with foreach

Comment: Sorry but I only need the <tr> and <td>'s from one table - The third.

Comment: so adapt the query to select the third table (//table[first()+2] = the third table)

Comment: Does the DOMX works with HTML? I get error: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMXPath::__construct() must be an instance of DOMDocument, string given in

Comment: When I write "$document" I mean the DOMDocument you created just above with code `$dom = new domDocument; 

/*** load the html into the object ***/ 
@$dom->loadHTML($html);`

Comment: Hmm cant get it to work. Is it not possible only to view the content from the third table with domDocument?

Comment: ->you can use getElementsByTagName and then ->item(2) and it is cool. I don't understand your issue.

Comment: Do you mean: $tables = $dom->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('table'); ?

Comment: No I don't. `$dom->getElementsById('table')->item(1);//the second table`

Comment: It says: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementsById()

Comment: be logical : td are in TR, so you must select tr before selecting td

Comment: I know that td comes after tr but I can't really se how i should code it.

Comment: if `td` coms after `tr` select TR like you selected table and then fetch your td

Comment: See my edit. Why can I only use item() once? In my edit3 I only missing to skip the first tr.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) on a [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php). This is an object and not an array. You need to use a [for loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) to iterate over it like this:

```
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
if( $tables->length < 3 ) {
  // Ahh crap! There is no third table!
}
$thirdTable = $tables->item(2);
$rows = $thirdTable->getElementsByTagName('tr');
for( $i = 0; $i < $rows->length; $i++ ) {
  $row = $rows->item( $i );
  $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
  $secondTd = $row->item( 1 );
  $thirdTd = $row->item( 2 );
}
```

Comment: Okay, But how about the two other table skipings?

Comment: I updated it to show how might get the third table. I strongly suggest you get comfortable reading the PHP manual (as linked in my answer in a few places) if you intend to continue doing PHP development. It will help you answer a lot of these types of questions.

Comment: I get error in the following lines:

$secondTd = $row->item(1);
$thirdTd = $row->item(2);

Comment: Typo. Should have been $cols->item( 1 ). It would also be wise to make sure $cols has as many elements as are expected (similar to making sure there are 3 tables before trying to access the third table.

Comment: Hmm when I trying to echo $cols->item( 1 ). I Get Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in

Comment: Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php for what properties/methods you need to call to get the values you want.